# How I can do swing complex layout Java

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, miglayout

I need a help about a java swing layout. I want do any thing like that (please see the image):

http://i1374.photobucket.com/albums/ag420/Bruno_Freitas/PROGRAMADEPONTUACcedilAtildeO_zpsebaf314e.jpg

I tried put a grid bag layout, but I could not insert a floatting JPanel with the content 10:00 (on image). Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please show your [minimal code attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and let us know how it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you would normally need to consider using multiple layouts, but in your case, a `GridBagLayout` should be capable of achieving what you want for the basic layout

For components that need to expand multiple columns, you can use `GridBagConstraints#gridwidth` and equally, for components that need to expand multiple rows `GridBagConstraints#gridheight`

As a whole, break down you layout requirements into individual areas of responsibility, for example, the score cards them selves have there own layout requirements and should be self contained components, this will reduce the layout complexity.

**Updated**

You could do the (core) layout in single container, but that is WAY to easy to break, instead, you should try and break the UI down into sections...

These are the, two, core sections that I see, there are subsections within them, but this is where I started...

[image: CoreSections]

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayoutTest();
    }

    public LayoutTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(new ScoreCardsPane(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            add(new TimePane(), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class TimePane extends JPanel {

        public TimePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            add(new TimeCard(), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class TimeCard extends JPanel {

        public TimeCard() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(new JLabel("TEMPO"), gbc);
            JLabel time = new JLabel("10:00");
            time.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            add(time, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class ScoreCardsPane extends JPanel {

        public ScoreCardsPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("PONTOS");
            add(topLabel, gbc);
            JLabel bottomLabel = new JLabel("PONTOS");
            gbc.gridy = 3;
            add(bottomLabel, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;

            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;

            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createScoreCard(), gbc);

        }

    }

    protected static JPanel createScoreCard() {

        JPanel card = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 100);
            }

        };
        card.setBackground(Color.RED);

        return card;

    }

}
```